# Inkscape autosave

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to enable an autosave after any operation I do in InkScape?

This would be really handy because sometimes it crashes, and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is annoying.

Comment: Is it really that annoying to repeat the work of one minute? How often does it crash per hour?

Comment: @userunknown Since I posted the question Inkscape got some nice updates and got stable. It's a pleasure to use it now. :) And yes, it's annoying to repeat the work, even I do it faster than first time, but it's terrible. :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. You can have an autosave but it is based on an interval with a 1 minute minumum, not on an action.

- Click on the Edit menu > Inkscape Preferences > Input/Output >
- Check "Enable autosave".

[image]

By the way, in case you did not know: Inkscape does an [emergency save](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/EmergencySave) when it crashes so you should be able to retrieve the file that was active while it crashed.

> When Inkscape crashes, it tries to save the document as a backup with following name:

```
<filename>.<datetime>.#
```

> If the document has not been saved yet, the name is:

```
inkscape-emergency.<datetime>.#
```

> Note, that there is no .svg file name ending.

> On Unix (Linux, Mac OS X, *BSD, etc.) Inkscape tries to save in the following paths:

> - Home directory (~/, $HOME, /home//)

> - /tmp/

> - In the current working directory

> (in that order).

Comment: That's also fine, but would it be possible to autosave the document each *5 seconds*? I know the emergency save, but for some reason it didn't work for me.

Comment: Probably no.. 1 minute minimum :( The emergency save: I think I saw a problem with non-english versions. Yours is Iberian probably?

Comment: I'm Romanian, having the Romanian keyboard layout, but the language is set to English, also the version is English...

Comment: The auto save got introduced in 0.47. Have not found the actual part that does this in the code yet; still have a look around the  tar file and the web for it (maybe it is easy to change ;) )

Comment: There is a really simple code change if you're into hacking the source.

Given that you have the source and can build inkscape, you need to edit src/inkscape.cpp and remove the `* 60` from the method `Application::autosave_init()`.

Comment: It should probably be saving on action, attached to the undo. And that property option needs more information about what it's doing.

Comment: The emergency save saved me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Inkscape 0.92 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I noticed it's slightly different to Rinzwind's accepted answer.

You can find the same option by going to:

```
Edit -> Preferences
```

Then in the popup window go to:

```
Input/Ouput -> Autosave
```

[image]